# Unable to Install Ops Hub Migration utility. Cannot connect to remote server

Tags: opshub

I am facing issue to install my Ops Hub migration Utility on my 2010 VM - Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise with 64 Bit Edition.

I get the following error when I run the utility after filling in the registration details
"Unable to connect to remote server, please check your internet connectivity or proxy settings."

- My internet is working completely fine.
- Also browser LAN has automatically detect settings too.

As I found I have tried to create the Environment Variable _Java_Options as well but with no luck.

http://www.opshub.com/main/ovsomu-proxy

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have username and password for the proxy setting? What about bypass of local addresses? Most likely, the _JAVA_OPTIONS is incorrectly set or not being picked by OVSMU tool.